# RSA sign in node.js and verify in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, rsa, node-rsa

I'm working on a way to secure the message I sent from a node.js server to a C++ application.

From node.js , I created a key pair.

I'm using node-rsa to read the public key on node.js side  ( https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa )

```
var rsa =  new nodeRSA(publicKeyBuffer  ,{encryptionScheme :'pkcs1'})
```

As my message can be long, I calculate a salted sha256 of the message before calling encrypt.

```
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(message + config.signSalt).digest('hex')
```

this part is working fine because I am able to generate the exact same hash on C++ side.

then, I'm calling the encrypt function of node-rsa to generate a buffer

```
const signature = rsa.encrypt(hash)
```

I tried various encoding , but as the data is sent through a websocket (+ MsgPack packing) the binary format is a good option

On C++ side , I am first reading the key for a char[]

```
const char keyStr[] = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" ..........

BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(keyStr, (int)strlen(keyStr)); // -1: assume string is null terminated

m_rsaPrivKey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (!m_rsaPrivKey)
        LogOutSys("ERROR: Could not load PRIVATE KEY! PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey FAILED: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
```

the key is read without errors, after that, I'm calculating the hash from the message, making a std::string from the unsigned char buffer

```
std::string hash = sha256(msg.c_str());

std::string signatureStr(signature.begin(), signature.end());

char *decrypt;

int decryptLen;

decrypt = new char[RSA_size(m_rsaPrivKey)];

decryptLen = RSA_private_decrypt((int)msg.size() + 1, (unsigned char*)msg.c_str(), (unsigned char*)decrypt, m_rsaPrivKey, RSA_NO_PADDING /* RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING */ );

if (decryptLen == -1)
{
    char errStr[130];
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), errStr);
    LogOutSys("Rsa::decrypt - Error decrypting string ssl error %s", errStr);
}

for (int i = 0; i < decryptLen; i++)
{
    decryptData.push_back(decrypt[i]);
}

delete decrypt;
```

the decrypt failed with the following error

Rsa::decrypt - Error decrypting string ssl error error:0406506C:lib(4):func(101):reason(108)

I tried various encoding and padding mode but always getting an error.

Comment: Why are you not using the `sign(buffer, [encoding], [source_encoding])` method on the javascript side (which is meant for signing and should perform hashing inside) ? The way you do it will not produce a correct signature (the padding for signature and encryption is different). It might help to use the `openssl` command line utility to verify key/signature/encryption correctness. Does `publicKeyBuffer` contain public or private key (as it should contain a private key for signature, this variable name is quite misleading)? Good luck!

Comment: it's the first time I'm doing this so maybe I m doing the wrong way (that's why I asking the question actually :) ) yes the publicKeyBuffer contains a public key. I thought if was possible to sign with public key and verify with private key but according to your answer maybe it s not the case.

Comment: You said "the key is read with errors". Did you mean _without_ errors? Otherwise that seems like the problem right there.

Comment: And yeah you should be able to encrypt with a public key and decrypt with a private key and vice versa.

Comment: worked on this today, still not able to make it works, I navigated between errors with reason(118), reason(108), reason(159). trying to change the encoding on node size dont help, the best way to get the data on C++ side without modification is to use a buffer (so no encoding option) , when I  manage to RSA_private_decrypt returning no errors, I ended with a signature of size 256 while RSA_private_decrypts return a buffer of size 64 (and the first 64 chars dont match)

Comment: Signing should be done with a private key, and verification with a public key, otherwise what you're doing is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

*(Assuming you want to sign using the private key on the nodejs side and verify using the public key on the openssl side)*

To sign string `Test` with sample private key, use e.g.:

```
NodeRSA=require('node-rsa');
key = new NodeRSA(null, {signingScheme: 'pkcs1-sha256'});
key.importKey('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nKXzq4lptzgfQIg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n', 'pkcs8');
signature=key.sign('Test', 'hex');
```

Giving a hex encoded signature:

```
'45f0c0672c8c07ecfe318b8ffa425c169ed2458ac6f0e4f1ffe0bcebec38cc3e59311858ed443d45f0dc81935ee0c490fa452b2f427d59a2c43fdd69f71f2b46d9e39072cb517b4afba5d5c66b26e14ca8a2900650b923fd77271deba84103d42c1f81619825d4987eeabc05401b0bc35bee08c59843aa94a535d2fb032b681b'
```

---

To verify this signature with openssl, use e.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(void) {

    // Read public key from memory
    EVP_PKEY *pubKey=NULL;
    {
        BIO * pubKeyPemBio = BIO_new_mem_buf("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCNhpKqFY9ZefTEISP2bMIHZzRt\n6OV0psnhoDXZk4EEOnFgiXLHAkund/p1hZd13u0scysaO6RzB03iVBk2aS81u35O\nWPyEliK9kLLMKZvCVFTgFEFVP6sGWD69AAgg0Cxi2lQcihYLyp3+aaZHa6DOtwBW\npJ+WJQj/ljOAErmcrwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", -1);
        if(pubKeyPemBio==NULL) { printf("Error at line %i\n", __LINE__); return 0; }
        pubKey=PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(pubKeyPemBio, &pubKey, NULL, NULL);
        BIO_free(pubKeyPemBio);
        if(pubKey==NULL) { printf("Error at line %i\n", __LINE__); return 0; }
    }

    // Verify signature
    {
        EVP_MD_CTX *ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
        if(ctx==NULL) { printf("Error at line %i\n", __LINE__); return 0; }

        int ret=EVP_DigestVerifyInit(ctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, pubKey);
        if(ret!=1) { printf("Error at line %i\n", __LINE__); return 0; }

        ret=EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(ctx, "Test", 4);
        if(ret!=1) { printf("Error at line %i\n", __LINE__); return 0; }

        ret=EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, "\x45\xf0\xc0\x67\x2c\x8c\x07\xec\xfe\x31\x8b\x8f\xfa\x42\x5c\x16\x9e\xd2\x45\x8a\xc6\xf0\xe4\xf1\xff\xe0\xbc\xeb\xec\x38\xcc\x3e\x59\x31\x18\x58\xed\x44\x3d\x45\xf0\xdc\x81\x93\x5e\xe0\xc4\x90\xfa\x45\x2b\x2f\x42\x7d\x59\xa2\xc4\x3f\xdd\x69\xf7\x1f\x2b\x46\xd9\xe3\x90\x72\xcb\x51\x7b\x4a\xfb\xa5\xd5\xc6\x6b\x26\xe1\x4c\xa8\xa2\x90\x06\x50\xb9\x23\xfd\x77\x27\x1d\xeb\xa8\x41\x03\xd4\x2c\x1f\x81\x61\x98\x25\xd4\x98\x7e\xea\xbc\x05\x40\x1b\x0b\xc3\x5b\xee\x08\xc5\x98\x43\xaa\x94\xa5\x35\xd2\xfb\x03\x2b\x68\x1b", 128);
        if(ret!=1) { printf("Error at line %i\n", __LINE__); return 0; }
        EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(ctx);
    }
    EVP_PKEY_free(pubKey);

    printf("All OK!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Some (random) notes:

- above code is just a working proof-of-concept for RSA sign/verify between nodejs and openssl. Please do not expect it to be a secure implementation with correct error handling, secure key lengths, secure against timing/side-channel attacks etc.
- signed string/buffer can be arbitrarily long as hashing is performed by *node-rsa*
- encoded public/private key can be obtained in nodejs using e.g. `key.exportKey('pkcs8-public')`/`key.exportKey('pkcs8')`
- select encoding that fits you (I used strings and hex-strings as they are clearly readable). You probably want to use buffers

Good luck!

Disclaimer: I am no crypto expert, so please do validate my thoughts.

---

Used private key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

With corresponding public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCNhpKqFY9ZefTEISP2bMIHZzRt
6OV0psnhoDXZk4EEOnFgiXLHAkund/p1hZd13u0scysaO6RzB03iVBk2aS81u35O
WPyEliK9kLLMKZvCVFTgFEFVP6sGWD69AAgg0Cxi2lQcihYLyp3+aaZHa6DOtwBW
pJ+WJQj/ljOAErmcrwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```